# .htaccess vs chmod what's the difference in terms of permission

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i've been wondering what's the difference between .htaccess and chmod on your web server? because when I execute on my terminal:

```
$sudo chmod -R -700 /var/www/html
```

and visit www.mysite.com (more or less access forbidden)

but I can also do this with .htaccess

again are there any difference such as permission on accessing the file?

Answer (score 0):

Chmod - system command for set permission. 
Wrong way in you case, because in that case apache has not permission on this files or directory
.htaccess - Apache2 web server instruction. 
How Apache should be show directory in your web project.